# python elasticsearch query for boolean

Tags: python, search, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, pyelasticsearch

I have the following query:

```
Bool(must=[Terms(avail_req=['Available'], boost=2.0), Terms(boost=2.0,
sale_rent=['Sale']), Nested(path='listings', query=Bool(should= 
[Terms(boost=2.0, listings.parents_id=[80]), Terms(boost=2.0,  
listings.loc_id=[80])]))])
```

Now the terms by default without `should` and `must` query (for eg  Terms(boost=2.0, sale_rent=['Sale'])) is what?

As these are should queries

```
query=Bool(should= [Terms(boost=2.0, listings.parents_id=[80]), Terms(boost=2.0,  
listings.loc_id=[80])]))])
```

I am getting results only for Terms(boost=2.0, listings.parents_id=[80]) but not for other one

Comment: Your question in indecipherable: you may wish to re-word it so it's understandable. You may also wish to give a small `working` snippet, along with `input` and expected `output.` See [ask]